# Rails app Staging environment crashing on Heroku with simple authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

Hello my fellow Rails developers. Any Rack specialist out there?

I have forked out my live app to a staging app whith a dedicated staging environment; for which I'm trying to setup a username/password authentication as per the excellent "Heroku Cookbook" from Mike Coutermarsh. My staging.rb file in the Environment folder looks like:

```
# Based on production defaults
require Rails.root.join('config/environments/production')
Jbts2018::Application.configure do
config.middleware.use '::Rack::Auth::Basic' do |user, password|
[user, password] == ['staging', ENV['STAGING_PASS']]
 end
end
```

As soon as I set the Heroku Environment as follows:

RACK_ENV:                 staging
RAILS_ENV:                staging

the app crashes miserably.

From the Heroku logs the interesting bits show:

```
2017-11-26T06:08:07.265653+00:00 app[api]: Set RACK_ENV config vars by user 
rodolphe@rgeant.name
2017-11-26T06:08:07.265653+00:00 app[api]: Release v63 created by user 
rodolphe@rgeant.name
2017-11-26T06:08:08.527577+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to 
starting
2017-11-26T06:08:11.994768+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `   bin/rails server -p 9534 -e staging`
2017-11-26T06:08:15.842600+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to 
crashed
2017-11-26T06:08:15.826934+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-11-26T06:08:15.765330+00:00 app[web.1]: 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-
5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:35:in `build': undefined method `   new' for "::Rack::Auth::Basic":String (NoMethodError)
2017-11-26T06:08:15.765347+00:00 app[web.1]: Did you mean?  next
```

There must be some error in the following snippet :

```
config.middleware.use '::Rack::Auth::Basic'
```

I'm not too sure what's wrong though.

Any idea will be most welcome.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't write the name of the class in quotes.

`config.middleware.use ::Rack::Auth::Basic`